# How to redirect using .htaccess so CMS is included?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Everytime I redirect using .htaccess file I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Never used an .htaccess file before so struggling to fix it.

I need to redirect from:

http://www.jfk-scotland.com

To

http://www.jfk-scotland.com/index.php/index.html

I have integrated a CMS so need it to redirect or it doesnt include the CMS.

Any help would be apprectiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /index.php/index.html
```